# Something has changed in In-app billings on Android

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-pay

I've spent last few days on testing in app purchases, and what I see is that something has changed in Google Play. Since yesterday I'm getting other responses in some cases and even logs in my Google Wallet are different than previous (check screenshot below).

[image: Difference between GW billing records since 27th of july]

**Here is my problem**

Lets give it such a scenario:

1. Try to purchase real subscription product without funds on associated credit card - ok Google play shows dialog and advices us to check Google Wallet, so I'm going there, everything looks good (except I have no money on my credit card - exactly it's a virtual prepaid card, and another thing is that when I click link to update payment informations I'm redirected to my transactions)
2. Cancel your order in Google Wallet
3. Try to purchase it once again and I get "You have already purchased this item, or purchase is still pending" dialog. No matter if transactions was restored and how much time goes off (now I'm about 24h after first try). I'm getting this response even if I have money on card

And finally I'm unable to purchase my products. **So my questions are - how to solve my problem? And what exactly has changed?** Except logs in Wallet and time latency between try to purchase and cancel notification on no funds (now its instant, but up to 27 it was few minutes - first comes Purchased status and then Canceled).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour and haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

I have experience same errors for about a few weeks. I've contacted with Google Play Support Team and they confirmed problems on their side. They also sad a fix is already in testing stage now and should be deployed soon.